# FSM aiogram проектирование

Tags: python, aiogram

Как правильно применить FSM к проекту, по каким критериям нужно разбивать действия на состояния и тд?

Comment: В зависимости от поставленной задачи, которую заранее вы разбили на подзадачи, для понимания полноты структуры вашего задания.